# Force pin for signing data(SignedXml)?

Tags: cryptography, certificate, x509certificate, smartcard, signing

I am testing this example : [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms148731(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms148731%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and it works great.

Im using a certificate that are loaded in to the certificates store(MY) from a smartcard.

The problem is that this code will never ask for a pin code? How can I force the pin code check?

Edit : Have also tried with this code and it works just as with the first one : http://ianreddy.wordpress.com/2011/02/14/sign-data-using-certificates-in-c/ (no pin code demand)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PIN is usually asked for by the CSP provider, i.e. the module that is developed by a hardware vendor and which maps the certificates from your hardware to windows certificate storage. It's possible that this module caches the PIN for the process or that you have not set the USER pin for the hardware (set only "admin's" pin).

Comment: I have a softeare called NETID that is communicating with the hardware(cardreader) are you suggesting that it is this software that prevents the pin code? When using a authentication certificate to communicate over WCF I will be prompted with a pin code dialog by the NETID. This is done first when the WCF channel is used. I am using a diffrent certificate when signing and this is done only on client(as you can see in the code).

Comment: @Banshee If I understood you right, you have two certificates in the card reader and you are prompted for the PIN on first access. I guess the driver caches this PIN for consequent accesses from the same process. Check the settings of the driver (many vendors provide a UI application to configure the driver) - maybe you can turn off PIN caching.

Comment: Thats correct, I got a couple of certificates to choose from that are copied from the card to the certificate store. I was under the impression that diffrent certificate also meant diffrent pin. I know that NETID(that copie and demand pin code) also have a pin cache. I will check if the pin code is the same on both certificates but I dont think so(almost sure that the paper that come with the id card hade 2 pin codes(one for authetication and one for signing)).

Comment: @Banshee In hardware devices there's usually one or two pins per device, not per data object (certificate, key etc.). Eg. PKCS#11 standard defines only uesr pin and admin pin for the *device* itself.